# Make mercurial NOT use xcode's filemerge

Tags: high-sierra, xcode

This is perhaps a question for hg as much as it is for macOS.

I just upgraded to macOS High Sierra(10.13.4) to install Xcode.

Before the upgrade, my mercurial was set up to use kdiff3 as the diff tool and I was happy with it.

After the upgrade, mercurial is now using the file merge tool that comes with xcode. I do not want hg to use the file merge tool and have not done any change for this to happen except install xcode.

The configuration in `~/.hgrc` looks as follows

```
[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3="/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3"

[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args = $base $local $other -o $output
pom_merge.priority = -100
pom_merge.premerge = True
pom_merge.args = -o $output $base $local $other
pom_merge.executable = /Users/username/codebases/apm/hg/secondbase/tools/hg-tools/pom_merge.py 

[merge-patterns]
**pom.xml = pom_merge

[extensions]
shelve=
rebase=
purge=
hgext.extdiff=
extdiff=
strip=

[tortoisehg]
vdiff =kdiff3
editor="/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3"
```

When I run `hg config`, which is supposed to show the combined settings from all hgrc files, it does the following entries, but I do not know where they come from

```
merge-tools.filemerge.executable=/Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge
merge-tools.filemerge.args=-left $other -right $local -ancestor $base -merge $output
merge-tools.filemerge.gui=True
merge-tools.filemergexcode.executable=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge
merge-tools.filemergexcode.args=-left $other -right $local -ancestor $base -merge $output
merge-tools.filemergexcode.gui=True
```

Does any one have any idea how to fix this so I can continue to use kdiff3 as my difftool instead of the xcode file merge?

Comment: I ended up uninstalling Xcode as I don't need it at the moment(It was required as a dependency for compiling some os specific modules. I'm building it now in docker).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I cannot seem to get rid of FIleMerge launching for 2-way diffs

Comment: @O'Rooney Not really. I ended up uninstalling Xcode and that reverted me back to the original behavior I wanted as I didn't really need Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Xcode installed, since I don't want to use FileMerge. However, I can spot that the path to your kdiff3 is inside quotes `"`, and it shouldn't. I tried here and it doesn't work like that.

The necessary configs to the .hgrc file to run kdiff3 as the vdiff tool in Mercurial (TortoiseHg) are:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.kdiff3 = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode installed, and TortoiseHg 6.1.3. By default it launches FileMerge for 2 way diffs (and also 3 way merge, IIRC).

I can fix this to use KDiff3 for both, by doing the following:

Menu > TortoiseHg > Preferences > Edit file

Add a section at the bottom:

```
[merge-tools]
kdiff3.args=--auto --L1 $labelbase --L2 $labellocal --L3 $labelother $base $local $other -o $output
kdiff3.diffargs=--L1 $plabel1 --L2 $clabel $parent $child
kdiff3.fixeol=True
kdiff3.gui=True
kdiff3.executable=/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

Click Save

Restart TortoiseHg (I think this is required to make it reload the setup).

Menu > TortoiseHg > Preferences

For 3 way merge tool, select KDiff3.

Just to note, the **reason** that FileMerge seems to be selected by default is that the MergeTools.rc that is supplied with TortoiseHg doesn't have any definitions for KDiff3 on Mac, only on Windows. I tried to figure out how to add a new definition but it didn't seem to help.